# local notification sound is not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

In iPhone app,

I am setting the local notification.

I am setting custom sound.

**I could not 'hear' any sound when notification comes.
Not even default sound.**

Neither in my iPod touch nor in my device.

Any body can help me to find out the reasons ?

Thanks very much.

here is code.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

localNotification.fireDate=[dateFormat dateFromString:alarm_date];

localNotification.alertBody = @"Alarm.";

localNotification.soundName = [filePath lastPathComponent];

//localNotification.soundName =soundname; 
//UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

localNotification.alertAction=@"Show";


[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

[localNotification release];
```

**Answer** 
Got the Silly Point : Notification sound all only play when your app is in the background or closed.
Sorry for this question. 
Any way thanks.

Comment: Stupid question but did you turn off the mute switch on the side of your iOS device?

Comment: I have checked on my device sound is playing well.

Comment: Oke, just want to make sure. Did you check wether you app's notification are aloud to play sounds? You can check this in the notification part of the settings app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the sound should be less than 30 seconds to be played as a notification sound

other thing:

According to the Apple Developer Documentation, you need to use "aiff", "caf" or "wav" files.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is use full to you.......

```
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];

    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"You have long time to care your......";
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1;
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitMinute;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    [localNotification release];
    localNotification = nil;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me I am trying.